# Add title if wordpress query exists?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to add a title if my query exists before my loop runs. I tried to use the concept from the advanced custom fields repeater code but if there's not a post that matches the query it still outputs the title. Is it possible to do this or am I just missing something?

```
<?php 
 $args = array( 
 'post_type' => 'boar', 
 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
 'meta_key' => 'breed', 
 'meta_value' =>'crossbred'
 );
 if ( have_posts() ) :
 echo '<h1 class="breed-title">Breed Title</h1>';
 echo '<ul class="small-block-grid-3">';
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
 <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question wasn't clear on whether you wanted to test the custom query or existing query. I'm assuming custom query.

you can test `$loop->have_posts()` before your custom loop but not before the query is run as obviously it is not populated yet.

```
$args = array( 
 'post_type' => 'boar', 
 'posts_per_page' => -1, 
 'meta_key' => 'breed', 
 'meta_value' =>'crossbred'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );


if($loop->have_posts()) :
     echo '<h1 class="breed-title">Breed Title</h1>';
     echo '<ul class="small-block-grid-3">';



while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
 <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 </ul>

endif;
```

Comment: you assumed right. Thanks. I have to wait a few more minutes before I can mark that as the correct answer.